# EV of 1 gapper versus connected

Tags: poker-strategy, pre-flop

There are less ways to hit a 1 gapper but if you hit it is better disguised

Assume only play suited connector under jack and above 4

Does a 1 gapper get paid off enough more to overcome the chance of hitting?

```
1 yyyxx
2 yyxxy
3 yxxyy
4 xxyyy

1 yyxyx
2 yxyxy
3 xyxyy
```

The chance of hitting goes down by a full 1/4
You need to get paid off 1 / (3/4) = 4/3

You are less likely to be beat by a larger straight.  They would need to be playing a 2 gapper and that only beats one of your 3.

Answer (score 1):

EV of connectors will be higher than one-gappers.

Sure, if you make a straight with a one-gapper it will be better disguised, BUT on most boards you will also have sets, flushes and boats in your range. It is not like you need to have one-gappers in your range to be not exploited. Also, even if you hit your straight, your opponent probably won't be thinking that you don't have this specific hand and him making a super big bluff is really unlikely.

On TV there sure are some hands that people play an odd hand and get paid off really big, but it doesn't happen frequently enough to implement in your game on a regular basis.

Connectors make more straights, stick with them.

Comment: Wow, you think the reason to play 1 gapper is to wait for super big bluff.

Comment: @Paparazzi not exactly. Either a big bluff or extra value and I am sure this won't happen frequently enough because of the reasons I stated

Answer (score 0):

Again I will not accept my own answer

The chance of hitting goes down by a full 1/4 compared to no gap
But 1 gapper is only giving up yyyxx which is one most vulnerable to an over straight

I have started to play suited 1 gappers in any situation I would play a suited connector.

Odds of 2 pair, trips, or flush does not go down.  It opens up my range and lets me see more flops.  I like to see flops in position for the right price.

Straights don't hit a lot but when they do you can often get paid off by 1 and 2 pair hands.  If you have the top end with no pair on the board and no flush draw then you get in with no risk.

I do think you get paid off bigger on 1 gappers to absorb the odds.

Against good players once they know you will play one gappers it is not as much disguised but does not slow me down.

The lowest I play is 65, 75 as you have 3 below not blocked by ace.

I don't like to play KJ, QJ, QT as those are hands that can hit one pair and cost you money.  But suited you have a big flush.  Also since they do not have 3 open slots above less ways to hit.

Mid not likely to open with mid to low suited connectors as you want players. It is the type of hand that if it hits it is likely the best hand. Late open raise with it to steal the blinds and you still have a lot of outs.

I like calling mid to late.  For 4 BB or less. I don't raise with it until I have shown down enough for them to figure it out.

You are going to flop an 8+ outter or 2 pr+ like 20%.  And then finish with 2 pr+ like 15%. So you need to make like 20 BB when you hit.  Against a premium hand you are 2:1 dog but need to release if not 8+ outter or 2 pr+.  You kind of need to take the heat and call up to 3/4 pot.  If they start opening for 1 pot then have to give up on suited connectors period.  Hopefully you pick up some blind steals also.

In the right spot I think 1 gappers are profitable.  Better hand for tournaments.